# Brew upgrade not working on latest OSX High Sierra beta version

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, xcode9beta6

I am getting the following error when upgrading brew packages

```
Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
```

Since I am using the beta osx version

```
High Sierra
System Version: macOS 10.13
Kernel Version: Darwin 17.0.0
```

It seems like I have to upgrade the beta Xcode version (Xcode 9) too, which I have downloaded and installed successfully from apple website https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Now, my question is how do I switch the Xcode version on my mac so that brew command uses the newly installed Xcode.

When I run `xcodebuild -version` I am getting the following output (installed from App store)

```
Xcode 8.3.3
Build version 8E3004b
```

whereas the beta version I have downloaded is from the apple website directly shows `9.0 beta 6`

[image]

Comment: sudo xcode-select --switch //Xcode-beta.app or rename your Xcode-beta.app to Xcode.app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Xcode is downloaded from the website the full command to switch is the following (considering you've moved the app to the application folder)

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app`

Answer (score 5):

I had to reinstall brew:

Uninstall it:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Then you can install it again:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: I hope this is not a dumb question but should you run that as 'sudo'

Comment: @AdamFreeman sorry, I hope I´m right but probably not, if it does not work, try with sudo :)